# Hidden details option of dataTables when loaded through model MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a table of employees which I fetch using `$.load` ajax call by sending back a `partialview` as below:

**Model Class**

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string AccountStatus{get; set;}
    public string LastLogin{get;set;}
    public string EmailAddress{get;set;}
    public string Contact {get;set;}
    public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

**PartialViewResult method in controller**

```
public PartialViewResult GetEmployeeDetails()
{
    List<EmployeeDetails> model=new List<EmployeeDetails>();
    using(var context=new ContextConnection())
    {
        var employees=(from e in context.tbl_employees select e).ToList();
        foreach(var employee in employees) //Fill the model
        {
            model.add(new EmployeeDetails(){
                 FirstName=employee.fname,
                 LastName=employee.lname,
                 AccountStatus=employee.acc_status,
                 LastLogin=employee.last_login,
                 EmailAddress=employee.email,
                 Contact=employee.contact,
                 Gender=employee.gender
            });
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_EmployeeDetails",model) //passing model back
}
```

**_EmployeeDetails View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.EmployeeDetails>

<table id="employee" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Account Status</th>
                <th>Last Login</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach(var emp in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@emp.FirstName + " " + @emp.LastName</td>
                <td>@emp.AccountStatus</td>
                <td>@emp.LastLogin</td>
                <td>@emp.EmailAddress</td>
            </tr>
         }
         </tbody>
</table>
```

From <kbd>**[this link](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)**</kbd> I was able to achieve the `UI` whatever given in the link

```
var table; //global variable
$('.loadEmployee').on('click',function(){
   $("#loadBody").load("/Admin/GetEmployeeDetails",function(){
         table=$("#employee").dataTable({
               "columns": [
                {
                    "className":      'details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { "data": "Full Name" },
                { "data": "Account Status" },
                { "data": "Last Login" },
                { "data": "Email Address" }
                ],
                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
         });
   }
})

function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d["Full Name"]+'</td>'+ //this is fine
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d["Contact Details"]+'</td>'+ //Need to get Contact here
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Gender:</td>'+
            '<td>d["Gender"]</td>'+ //Need to get Gender here
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#employee tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
 });
```

My question here is:

> **I have model filled with all the data but how to display the extra data which is in the model (Contact),(Gender) in `format` function**

The demo given in the above link uses `.txt` files to extract data but nowhere it is mentioned how to do this with `model` data according to my above scenario. The `+` link and `-` links are working fine except the model values for `Contact` and `Gender` are not getting displayed. One scenario I am thinking of is add all these as `td`s in `foreach` and hide them so that I can get the column values as I am getting now for displayed data. But then this would be heavy when there is huge amount of columns to be displayed. Any ideas/lights on this is much appreciated.

Comment: You could add the values as `data-*` attributes, perhaps to the `<tr>` element - `<tr data-contact="emp.contact" data-gender="emp.Gender">` and then get them in the `$('#employee tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {` function using `var contact = tr.data('contact');` etc and pass those values to your `format()` function

Comment: Oh yea!! Come on!! How silly I missed this part.. :) Please post this as answer @StephenMuecke and I shall accept it.. :) but one more doubt here.. If you have seen that link they get data from some `txt` file and they bind but still `data` which aren't displayed were able to be fetched from `row.data()`? How does that work? any idea.. :)

Comment: Don't use the dataTable plugin so not sure, but I'll have look a bit later and see what I can find out

Comment: Sure buddy @StephenMuecke and please do post it as answer.. :)

Comment: OK, I think I know whats happening. The example you linked to is using a `datasource` to populate the table, in this case `../ajax/data/objects.txt` which is json data (you can see it by clicking on the Ajax tab of the example) so the `"ajax": ...` option reads the data and stores it (I assume as `data-*` attributes in each row). Because the json includes a property for `extn` its value is stored even though its not displayed in a column. I presume that the `row.data()` function then read these values so they are available.

Comment: Yea I saw that part but couldn't grasp much on that, but I think it is not stored as `data-*` because I inspected the table row and did not found it there.. May be some other technique.. Better I need to see `data()` function and understand what's happening there.. :)

Comment: Much the same as per my answer (the only difference being because the `data-*` attributes are added programatically, you don't see them when viewing the page source). I suspect if you were to use `"ajax": '@Url.Action(someMethod)` that initialized your collection and had `return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` you would access to the other properties in the `d` object

Comment: You don't physically see `data-` attributes if you add them using javascrip/jquery which would explain why you don't see them

Comment: Agree, but then there is a huge process. When I opt for that particular approach it makes me to write my own `filtering`, `sorting` etc., functionalities which is a headache again. But my doubt was if it was using `data-*` shouldn't that be visible on Inspect Element? But it is 100% true as you said that I need to use `ajax` property of `dataTables` to get all the values in `d` object.. :)

Comment: Oh alright.. Never knew about hiding attributes.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to add the 'extra' values as `data-*` attributes in the table row.

```
@foreach(var emp in Model)
{
  <tr data-contact="emp.contact" data-gender="emp.Gender">
    ....
  </tr>
}
```

and then extract them in the buttons click event and pass those values to the `format()` function

```
$('#employee tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var contact = tr.data('contact');
  var gender = tr.data('gender');
  // you could also add the following as an option to using the row data
  var fullName = tr.children('td').eq(1).text();
  var row = table.row( tr );
  if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(format(row.data(), contact, gender)).show();
    // or row.child(format(fullName, contact, gender)).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

and then change the `format()` function to accept the additional parameters

```
function format(d, contact, gender) {
```

Comment: Awesome buddy!! Thank you much.. :)